Periodic fluctuations in photodiode signal, possible laser problem
Background:
I have a MaiTai BB Ti:sapph pulsed laser that I use for pump-probe transient reflectivity experiments. The output of the laser is split into pump and probe beams. The pump beam goes through a PEM that is modulated at 100kHz, and the probe beam goes through a delay stage that provides the time resolution for the experimental measurements. The probe beam is reflected off of the sample surface and measured via a photodiode and a lock-in amplifier.
The problem that I am having is that there are these weird fluctuations in the reflectivity signal. I also saw what looked like a square wave in the photodiode signal which are present even if I bypass the sample and direct the probe beam straight into the photodiode.
Here is a graph of these fluctuations. The left axis is photodiode voltage and the bottom axis is time. Each measured point is an average of 128 samples taken about every second.

I am curious if anyone has seen this before, if my laser is in some weird mode, or if a degraded photodiode can cause this phenomenon. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there is a better place I should post this please let me know!

Have you measured your laser's input voltage?  Perhaps there is some periodic fluctuation in your lab's line voltage caused by some other equipment cycling on and off.

How are you splitting the beam? Can you just monitor the output beam power before the splitter? Is the beam splitter polarized?
